# Mod_Wsgi PythonHome not working

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, mod-wsgi, wsgi

So I made the mistake of running a Ubuntu Server (12.04). I have Python3 installed and the python3 version of of mod_wsgi.

Apache2 starts - but leaves the following error log:

```
[Mon May 05 11:00:24 2014] [error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.7.2+', found '2.7.3'.
[Mon May 05 11:00:24 2014] [error] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[Mon May 05 11:00:24 2014] [error] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib/python2.7/:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/$
[Mon May 05 11:00:24 2014] [notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 80 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Mon May 05 11:00:24 2014] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Mon May 05 11:00:24 2014] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.2.2+.
[Mon May 05 11:00:24 2014] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Mon May 05 11:00:24 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 with Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.3 mod_wsgi/3.3 configured$
[Mon May 05 11:00:25 2014] [notice] child pid 10860 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon May 05 11:00:25 2014] [notice] child pid 10861 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon May 05 11:00:25 2014] [notice] child pid 10863 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon May 05 11:00:27 2014] [notice] child pid 10864 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon May 05 11:00:27 2014] [notice] child pid 10865 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Here is my WSGI.conf

```
<IfModule mod_wsgi.c>

WSGIPythonHome /usr/bin/python3.2
WSGIPythonPath /home/user/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/

</IfModule>
```

I've got nothing out of 2 hours of googling - so I'm very tempted to just install a different server OS, but re-uploading / re-parsing the Bitcoin blockchain would take at least a day.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854023/how-can-i-rebuild-my-mod-wsgi-to-use-python-2-7-3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WSGIPythonHome will not do anything because you are also loading mod_python into your Apache instance. In that case, mod_python overrides what Python version is being used.

This is mentioned in the documentation for WSGIPythonHome.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome

Also read:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Using_ModPython_and_ModWsgi
- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Python_Version_Mismatch
- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Incompatible_ModPython_Versions

Also, WSGIPythonHome is not meant to be set to the path for the Python executable anyway. So that would have been completely ignored even if you had only been using just mod_wsgi.

So, if you don't need mod_python, stop loading it into Apache.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives    WSGIPythonHome: Absolute path to Python prefix/exec_prefix directories.

Comment: IOW, 'import sys; sys.prefix'. It isn't referring to the filename of the 'python' executable. The filename of the 'python' executable is 'sys.executable` which is different and not a 'prefix'.

Comment: Also see the explanation of PYTHONHOME at https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME

Comment: Thanks. I almost got it- but now there's another error: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named encodings

Comment: mhm, the manual isn't very clear on that. For example: "Note: The WSGIPythonExecutable directive described here has been removed in mod_wsgi version 2.0. The WSGIPythonHome directive should be used instead." (implying that the later is a replacement). Anyways I'm trying to run it without Pythonhome with the default python3.2 install, which is still giving that encoding error. I'll try and rebuild compiling to a fresh virtualenv.

Comment: What encoding error? Your log messages show a segmentation fault, which is going to be caused by mixing mod_python and mod_wsgi using different versions. If you still have segmentation fault even after dropping mod_python, then look at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API which is the typical cause.